# Calling a new Activity from within Runnable

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-intent

I have a flow to handle in andoid :

Suppose I am in Activity 1 and then there is one API say https://status.com/key which tells me whether I need to navigate to Activity 2 or stay on Activity 1 itself.

So in Activity-1 I have put the HttpRequest call inside runnable thread and I am continuously pinging that API after every second to know its response. The moment I get a response "yes" I navigate to Activity-2 (Google Maps Activity).

But what I noticed is even after navigating to Activity-2, the Runnable thread in Activity-1 is continuously running and as a result of which the Activity-2(Google maps activity) keeps loading again and again undesirably. How do I stop the runnable thread in Activity-1 :

> 1. Tried Thread.stop() // Not working
> 2. System.exit(0) //is a bad option

```
final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String myUrl="https://app.herokuapp.com/users/userredirection-pickup/"+ridetrackingno;
                Log.d("URL",myUrl);
                HttpGetRequest getRequest = new HttpGetRequest();
                try{
                    String result = getRequest.execute(myUrl).get();
                    JSONArray j=new JSONArray(result);
                    JSONObject jo= j.getJSONObject(0);
                    String r=jo.getString("status");
                    if(r.equals("yes")){
                        Intent show = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), Riding.class);
                        show.putExtra("Username",username);
                        show.putExtra("Phone",phone);

                        startActivity(show);
                    }
                } catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(r, 2000);
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried calling new activity 2 using runOnUiThread() ?

Comment: @Deepakkaku Please check the edited answer with code snippet. How can I do the same with runOnUiThread.

Comment: why not call the handler in else part?

Comment: @AbdulAli sorry didn't get you. My concern is how to stop this thread, once API returns "yes" and I navigate to next activity. But this thread keeps running in background as a result of which Intent gets executed multiple times leading to flickering of new Activity getting loaded again and again or the app crashes

Answer (score 0):

try this. Maybe it will work

```
final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String myUrl="https://app.herokuapp.com/users/userredirection-pickup/"+ridetrackingno;
                Log.d("URL",myUrl);
                HttpGetRequest getRequest = new HttpGetRequest();
                try{
                    String result = getRequest.execute(myUrl).get();
                    JSONArray j=new JSONArray(result);
                    JSONObject jo= j.getJSONObject(0);
                    String r=jo.getString("status");
                    if(r.equals("yes")){
                        try {
                             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                             @Override
                             public void run() {
                                 Intent show = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), Riding.class);
                                 show.putExtra("Username",username);
                                 show.putExtra("Phone",phone);

                                 startActivity(show);
                    }
                });
                Thread.sleep(300);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                    }
                } catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(r, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I was saying was this

```
if(r.equals("yes")){
    Intent show = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), Riding.class);
    show.putExtra("Username",username);
    show.putExtra("Phone",phone);

    startActivity(show);
} else {
    handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
}
```